# Object can be disposed more than once in method error CA202

Tags: vb.net

Hi I've looked at all the dispose links and still can't figure out what I'm supposed to do to remove this error from my code.

```
Dim foundBlank As Boolean
Dim builtMaster As String = Prefix & "_FinalDeliverable.sgm"
Dim newBuiltMasterFilePath = IO.Path.Combine(searchDir, builtMaster)
Dim builtMasterDoc As String = newBuiltMasterFilePath
Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(builtMasterDoc)
    For Each line As String In lines1
        If line.Length > 0 Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            foundBlank = False
        Else
            foundBlank = True
        End If
    Next
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End Using
```

The only other place I'm using the Close function is

```
    Response = MsgBox("File 'FinalDeliverable.sgm' has been created.", vbOKOnly, "SGM Status")
    If Response = vbOK Then    ' User chose Yes.
        Close()
    Else    ' User chose No.
        ' Perform some action.
    End If
```

Comment: Remove the `sw.Close()` statement as it will be called by the `End Using`

Comment: Thank you! that worked.

Comment: Your Stream is declared in with a `Using` statement. A `Using` block is a `Try/Finally` block under the hood. It calls `Close()` in it's `Finally` block (in this case, `Close()` acts as `Dispose()` ). Calling `Close()`, in this scenario, you're trying to `Dispose()` of the Stream twice, which might cause an exception later, trying to dispose of an already disposed object (it actually doesn't happen, there's a fail-safe check in the `Finally` block).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in fact trying to Dispose your stream twice.

By using a `Using` block, you ensure that the object you created will be disposed at the end of the block. This is good practice, keep it up ;-)

So your code could be translated like this :

```
Try
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(builtMasterDoc)
    For Each line As String In lines1
        If line.Length > 0 Then
            sw.WriteLine(line)
            foundBlank = False
        Else
            foundBlank = True
        End If
    Next
    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
Finally
    sw.Dispose()
End Try
```

`Close()` calls `Dispose()`, so in the end you call the Dispose method twice. Although MSDN says at multiple stages that it should work, it actually doesn't...

From [Stream.Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.dispose?view=netframework-4.8):

> Dispose() can be called multiple times by other objects.

From [StreamWriter.Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) :

> Dispose can be called multiple times by other objects.

Maybe newer version of .Net framework solve the problem.